# OrbitBehavior for multiple Canvas3D

Tags: java-3d

java3d newbie here. I learned the basics. Managed to create two canvases looking at the same object. I also managed to use the OrbitBehavior to rotate the platform with the mouse:

```
OrbitBehavior orbit = new OrbitBehavior(canvas1, 
OrbitBehavior.REVERSE_ALL);
orbit.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
ViewingPlatform vp = universe.getViewingPlatform();
vp.setViewPlatformBehavior(orbit);
```

Thing is, no matter if I use canvas1 or canvas2 on the constructor above , both both canvases rotate together. So not too sure what the reference is for? What I wanted was to be able to rotate each view independently depending on which canvas the mouse is over. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer myself. I need two ViewingPlatform's which is not available in SimpleUniverse. In case someone finds this useful, below is the code that creates two Canvas3D's and each platform controlled by the mouse independently.

```
        VirtualUniverse u = new VirtualUniverse();
    Locale locale = new Locale(u);
    BranchGroup scene = new Scene(); // this is my own BranchGroup derived class for the geometry 
    locale.addBranchGraph(scene);

    GraphicsConfigTemplate3D gc3D = new GraphicsConfigTemplate3D();
    gc3D.setSceneAntialiasing( GraphicsConfigTemplate.PREFERRED );
    GraphicsDevice gd[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();

    Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(gd[0].getBestConfiguration( gc3D ));
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    ViewPlatform vp = new ViewPlatform();
    vp.setViewAttachPolicy( View.RELATIVE_TO_FIELD_OF_VIEW );
    ViewingPlatform viewingp = new ViewingPlatform();
    viewingp.setViewPlatform(vp);
    locale.addBranchGraph(viewingp);
    View view = new View();
    PhysicalBody pb = new PhysicalBody();
    PhysicalEnvironment pe = new PhysicalEnvironment();
    view.setPhysicalEnvironment( pe );
    view.setPhysicalBody( pb );
    view.attachViewPlatform( vp );
    view.addCanvas3D( canvas);
    OrbitBehavior orbit = new OrbitBehavior(canvas, OrbitBehavior.REVERSE_ALL);
    orbit.setSchedulingBounds(Scene.worldBounds);
    viewingp.setViewPlatformBehavior(orbit);

    Canvas3D canvas2 = new Canvas3D(gd[0].getBestConfiguration( gc3D ));
    canvas2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    ViewPlatform vp2 = new ViewPlatform();
    vp2.setViewAttachPolicy( View.RELATIVE_TO_FIELD_OF_VIEW );
    ViewingPlatform viewingp2 = new ViewingPlatform();
    viewingp2.setViewPlatform(vp2);
    locale.addBranchGraph(viewingp2);
    View view2 = new View();
    PhysicalBody pb2 = new PhysicalBody();
    PhysicalEnvironment pe2 = new PhysicalEnvironment();
    view2.setPhysicalEnvironment( pe2 );
    view2.setPhysicalBody( pb2 );
    view2.attachViewPlatform( vp2 );
    view2.addCanvas3D( canvas2);
    OrbitBehavior orbit2 = new OrbitBehavior(canvas2, OrbitBehavior.REVERSE_ALL);
    orbit2.setSchedulingBounds(Scene.worldBounds);
    viewingp2.setViewPlatformBehavior(orbit2);
```